# Standard Android menu icon for multiselect action

Tags: android, icons, menuitem

In my first application there is an activity using a `GridView` layout and an option menu. One of the menu items is "Multiselect" (the same that you can see in the standard Gallery application when you navigate a gallery). My current problem is that I can't find the standard multiselect icon anywhere. I've tried the following:

- Eclipse completion capabilities by typing android.R.drawable. and inspecting the list that eclipse shows to me
- searching the `android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-X/data/res/drawable-XX`
- searching https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/res
- visiting http://androiddrawableexplorer.appspot.com/ and similar websites

Where can I find the multiselect icon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the icon. After googling a little bit I found that GridView doesn't implement native support of multiple selection items. So the multiselect icon is not a standard Android icon and is not distributed with the SDK. The icon is part of the camera application. You can see it in [CyanogenMod repo android_packages_apps_Gallery](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_Gallery) under /res/drawable-hdpi. The icon filename is ic_menu_multiselect_gallery.png.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the icon you are referring to on my build (Android 4.1.1) but when looking for system drawables I have found them in the SDK under a path like;

`C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-16\data\res\drawable-<your_screen_res>`

The "more" icon for menus is called `ic_menu_moreoverflow_<some style>_<some theme>.png`. I'm sure the icon you are looking for is there...

**Edit**

Went away and found the icon by setting up an emulator at 2.1, here it is.

Look similar to `ic_menu_mark` and `btn_check_off` but admittedly not quite the same!

[image: The multiselect icon]

Comment: Well, my Android device runs the old 2.1 version. Anyway, I'm not looking for the "more" icon. I don't know the exact filename of the icon I'm looking for, I just know that in the Gallery app it appears in the menu item whose text is "Multiselect". As I said I've already searched the SDK res/drawableX directories without luck.

Comment: Oh so you did. Apologies. Have a look on the higher API level directories regardless. They are just resources so can be copied over to any API level. Failing that post a screenshot of the icon! :)

Comment: Thanks for posting the screenshot of the icon. Unfortunately I'm still unable to find it under the SDK directories (API 7 or higher). Moreover, I expected to find the "Multiselect" string in a strings.xml file but I failed again. I'm really puzzled. I suppose I'll have to use the ic_menu_mark icon or something looking similar :-(